# CSS from memory cache instead of disk cache

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

I am caching CSS with .htaccess. My .htaccess code is as follows:

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(css|html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536050"
 </FilesMatch>
```

It is loading from disk cache, which is taking around 500 ms and with memory cache it may take less than 500 ms or 0 ms.
So Is it possible to load CSS from memory cache instead of the browser?
And if possible then please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: Look for `cache` in your server side language

Comment: I am using PHP 7

Comment: Well, at SO we don't do search and code writing for users. Just check its docs and you'll find the answer.

Comment: Yes I know that , but I am asking this because my js is loading from memory cache and css from disk cache

Comment: So you just answered your question

Comment: That’s most likely a decision the browser makes on its own - and that is how it should be. Would be rather ridiculous, if websites could decide what my system keeps in memory, and what it caches elsewhere.